# Regex doesn't appear to process ampersands correctly

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am using the RegEx `[^A-Za-z0-9-_ &]` to remove everything but A-Z, a-z, 0-9,-,_,spaces and &.

It's completely working apart from the ampersands. It won't allow ampersands between other characters and will allow some ampersands through if I type a multiple of them in a row.

It works perfectly when I check it at https://regexr.com/ so this is something specific in the VB.

- I have tried changing where in the RegEx the ampersand is located.
- I have tried escaping it with a backslash.
- I have tried using `Regex.Escape`.
- I have tried using the hex charcode instead of an ampersand.

Below is my test code using a label control to show what the regex is doing:

```vb
Private Sub TextBoxSearch_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles TextBoxSearch.TextChanged
    Dim search As String = Regex.Replace(TextBoxSearch.Text, "[^A-Za-z0-9-_ &]", "")
    Label1.Text = search
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some menu items and so on can have shortcut keys assigned to them, for example:

[image]

To indicate that the following character is to be underlined, an ampersand is used. So in the above image, the "History" menu would have its text set to "Hi&story".

A side-effect of that is that if you have an ampersand in the text of a control, such as a label, which uses that functionality then the ampersand will disappear and the following character will be underlined - unless you have "&&" which tells it to show just a single "&".

To switch off that behaviour for a control, set the [.UseMnemonic Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.label.usemnemonic?view=netframework-4.8) to `False`, e.g.

```
Label1.UseMnemonic = False
```

Comment: That was it, thank you! 

So it seems the actual code was fine the whole time and it was the label as you said. Changed that property to false and it now shows what I am expecting.